# Input gets changed inside a scriptblock

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I have this script with a scriptblock:

```
$RoboArgs = @{
  Source = '01'
  Target = '02'
  ExtraArgs = '/e', '/purge'
}
Write-Host @RoboArgs
Start-ThreadJob -InputObject $RoboArgs -ScriptBlock {
  . robocopy_invoke.ps1
  Write-Host @input
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

I want to call a function defined in the robocopy_invoke.ps1 module using the input parameter (`Invoke-Robocopy @RoboArgs`), but the input parameter's contents somehow get changed once it enters the scriptblock.
Here's the output:

```
-Target: 02 -ExtraArgs: /e /purge -Source: 01
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+<GetReadEnumerator>d__20[System.Object]
```

Why is the output different for the two `Write-Host` calls?
How can I make the second one like the first one?

Comment: You want `@args`, not `@input`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm not seeing a mention of `@args` in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob. What does that stand for?

Comment: `$args` is not specific to the ThreadJob module: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use '-InputObject' to pipe objects into the job (retrieve using $input).
So `Start-ThreadJob -InputObject $RoboArgs -ScriptBlock {}` is equivalent to `$RoboArgs | Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {}`

What you need instead is '-ArgumentList' (retrieve using $args):

```
$RoboArgs = @{
  Source = '01'
  Target = '02'
  ExtraArgs = '/e', '/purge'
}
$RoboArgs

Start-ThreadJob -ArgumentList $RoboArgs -ScriptBlock {
  $args
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Example 2 (unpack $args arrays)

```
$RoboArgs = @{
  Source = '01'
  Target = '02'
  ExtraArgs = '/e', '/purge'
}
Write-Host @RoboArgs

Start-ThreadJob -ArgumentList $RoboArgs -ScriptBlock {
  $robo = $args[0]
  Write-Host @robo
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Example 3 (explicitly define parameters instead of using $args)

```
$RoboArgs = @{
    Source    = '01'
    Target    = '02'
    ExtraArgs = '/e', '/purge'
}
Write-Host @RoboArgs


Start-ThreadJob -ArgumentList $RoboArgs -ScriptBlock {
    param ( $myRoboArgs )
    Write-Host @myRoboArgs
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Comment: They're still different when using `-ArgumentList`. `Write-Host @RoboArgs` returns `-Target: 02 -ExtraArgs: /e /purge -Source: 01` while `Write-Host @args` now returns `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`. Just calling the variable (`@input`) worked with `-InputObject` as well so I don't see how `args` helps.

Comment: @gargoylebident, $args is an array of arguments. In this case, array of one argument. if you want to see exactly the same output using Write-Host , then use $args[0] - see updated answer

Comment: if you are not comfortable with $args, then you can explicitly define parameters in your scriptblock (the same syntax as function). see addtional example